# Draw a tennis court

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

[image: tennis field with paths]

I am new to TikZ, and I don't know to draw such a complicated fied.
I know just to draw a rectangle like:

```
\tikz \draw[fill=brown] (0,0) rectangle (10,5) (1cm);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may want to define a `pic` for that. I just copied the dimensions from Wikipedia and used them to define a pic `tennis court`. For the players, one does not really have many options, only 15, outside hibernation time it will be 16. This also installs a local coordinate system that makes it easier to place the players, `(-1,-1)` is the bottom left corner and `(1,1)` the top right corner. **EDIT**: Added the center service line, big thanks to Fortega.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\newsavebox\Koala
\newsavebox\Penguin
\sbox\Koala{\tikz{\koala[cricket=blue,scale=0.5]}}
\sbox\Penguin{\tikz{\penguin[cricket=red,scale=0.5]}}
\tikzset{pics/tennis court/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tennis court/##1}}
 \path[tennis court/back] (-1.2*\pv{scale}*11.98,-1.4*\pv{scale}*10.97/2) 
    rectangle ++ (1.2*\pv{scale}*2*11.98,1.4*\pv{scale}*10.97);
 \path[tennis court/markers,line width=2mm*\pv{scale},tennis court/surface] 
    (-11.98*\pv{scale},-10.97*\pv{scale}/2) 
        rectangle ++ (2*\pv{scale}*11.98,10.97*\pv{scale});
  \path[tennis court/markers,line width=1.5mm*\pv{scale}] 
   (-11.98*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- 
   (11.98*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-11.98*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- 
   (11.98*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-6.4*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- (-6.4*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-6.4*\pv{scale},0) -- (6.4*\pv{scale},0)
   (6.4*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- (6.4*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-11.98*\pv{scale},0) -- (-11.5*\pv{scale},0)
   (11.98*\pv{scale},0) -- (11.5*\pv{scale},0);
  \path[tennis court/net,line width=1mm*\pv{scale}]
  (0,-1.1*\pv{scale}*10.97/2) circle[radius=1.5mm*\pv{scale}]
   --    (0,1.1*\pv{scale}*10.97/2) circle[radius=1.5mm*\pv{scale}];
  \path (0,0) coordinate(-center)
    (11.98*\pv{scale},0) coordinate(-X)
    (0,10.97*\pv{scale}/2) coordinate(-DY)
    (0,8.23*\pv{scale}/2) coordinate(-SY);
}},
tennis court/.cd,surface/.style={fill=green!80!black},
back/.style={fill=green!60!black},
markers/.style={draw=white},scale/.initial=0.5,
net/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic (center court) {tennis court};
 \begin{scope}[shift={(center court-center)},
    x={($(center court-X)-(center court-center)$)},
    y={($(center court-SY)-(center court-center)$)},
    text=white,font=\large\sffamily]
  \path (-1.1,-0.4) node[label=below:B](B){\usebox\Koala};
  \draw[thick,orange!80!red,shorten >=-4cm] (B) -- (0,1) coordinate(t);
  \draw[thick,orange!80!red,shorten >=-4cm] (B) -- (0,-1) coordinate(b);
  \path let \p1=($(t)-(B)$),\p2=($(b)-(B)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
    in ($(B)+(\n1/2+\n2/2:2cm)$) coordinate (aux)
    (intersection cs:first line={(B)--(aux)}, second line={(1.1,-1)--(1.1,1)})
    node[label=below:A](A){\usebox\Penguin};
  \draw[ultra thick,red]    (B)--(A);
  \pic[draw,thick,angle radius=2cm] {angle=A--B--t};
  \pic[draw,thick,angle radius=2.2cm] {angle=b--B--A};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The penguin chooses their position depending on the koala's position.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\newsavebox\Koala
\newsavebox\Penguin
\sbox\Koala{\tikz{\koala[cricket=blue,scale=0.5]}}
\sbox\Penguin{\tikz{\penguin[cricket=red,scale=0.5]}}
\tikzset{pics/tennis court/.style={code={
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/tennis court/##1}}
 \path[tennis court/back] (-1.2*\pv{scale}*11.98,-1.4*\pv{scale}*10.97/2) 
    rectangle ++ (1.2*\pv{scale}*2*11.98,1.4*\pv{scale}*10.97);
 \path[tennis court/markers,line width=2mm*\pv{scale},tennis court/surface] 
    (-11.98*\pv{scale},-10.97*\pv{scale}/2) 
        rectangle ++ (2*\pv{scale}*11.98,10.97*\pv{scale});
  \path[tennis court/markers,line width=1.5mm*\pv{scale}] 
   (-11.98*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- 
   (11.98*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-11.98*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- 
   (11.98*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-6.4*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- (-6.4*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (6.4*\pv{scale},-8.23*\pv{scale}/2) -- (6.4*\pv{scale},8.23*\pv{scale}/2)
   (-6.4*\pv{scale},0) -- (6.4*\pv{scale},0)
   (-11.98*\pv{scale},0) -- (-11.5*\pv{scale},0)
   (11.98*\pv{scale},0) -- (11.5*\pv{scale},0);
  \path[tennis court/net,line width=1mm*\pv{scale}]
  (0,-1.1*\pv{scale}*10.97/2) circle[radius=1.5mm*\pv{scale}]
   --    (0,1.1*\pv{scale}*10.97/2) circle[radius=1.5mm*\pv{scale}];
  \path (0,0) coordinate(-center)
    (11.98*\pv{scale},0) coordinate(-X)
    (0,10.97*\pv{scale}/2) coordinate(-DY)
    (0,8.23*\pv{scale}/2) coordinate(-SY);
}},
tennis court/.cd,surface/.style={fill=green!80!black},
back/.style={fill=green!60!black},
markers/.style={draw=white},scale/.initial=0.5,
net/.style={draw=orange,fill=orange}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic (center court) {tennis court};
 \begin{scope}[shift={(center court-center)},
    x={($(center court-X)-(center court-center)$)},
    y={($(center court-SY)-(center court-center)$)},
    text=white,font=\large\sffamily]
  \path (-1.1,{0.6*sin(\X)})    node[label=below:B](B){\usebox\Koala};
  \draw[thick,orange!80!red,shorten >=-4cm] (B) -- (0,1) coordinate(t);
  \draw[thick,orange!80!red,shorten >=-4cm] (B) -- (0,-1) coordinate(b);
  \path let \p1=($(t)-(B)$),\p2=($(b)-(B)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
    in ($(B.center)+({\n1/2+\n2/2}:2cm)$)coordinate(aux)
    (intersection cs:first line={(B)--(aux)}, second line={(1.1,-1)--(1.1,1)})
    node[label=below:A](A){\usebox\Penguin};
  \draw[ultra thick,red]    (B)--(A);
  \draw[ultra thick,red]    (B)--(aux);
  \pic[draw,thick,angle radius=2cm] {angle=A--B--t};
  \pic[draw,thick,angle radius=2.2cm] {angle=b--B--A};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This shows that penguins are smart (beyond having invented Linux ;-).

Comment: Where is the tennis ball? :-) my upvote ↑.

Comment: @Sebastiano I think the bear stole it. ;-)

Comment: how to add the lines?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I used this one `\draw[red,very thick] plot[mark=*] coordinates {
   (-1.1,-0.2) (1.1,0.3)};`

from a code you provided in another question and it worked so thanks again ;)

Comment: @Math512 I also added some lines....

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Always brilliant thank you

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  I was just wondering how to add an extra detail:

make the red line start from the exact positions of A and B

Comment: Seems like you are missing the center service line ;-)

Comment: @Fortega You are right. I added it now. Thanks!!

Comment: As usual you are great...